# How do i check height when modeling a character?

Tags: modeling

i cant tell how tall my characters/buildings will be in cm or feet or anything really, in engine when the "scale" of the models just say 1 or 1.6 ect

using edge length in the overlay doesnt help at all as it seems relative to the objects starting scale, what i mean by that is when i create a cube and leave its scale as is and check its edge length it says 2m, when i creat cube and scale it up it also says its edge length is 2m

what im trying to do is create a cube and scale it up to be say 20 ft tall or 100 ft tall, really just something i can use as a "ruler" to accuratly judge the size of an object or height of a charater.

all the models will be going to unreal engine which apparently is 1:1 with blenders units im told

Comment: If you activate the measureit addon you can create lines that show the lengths between vertices with can be used to figure out the scale of different objects or characters.

Comment: when i do that it says my character model is 12.7601 m, what is that in cms or inches or any real world measurement? i dont know what 12 blender m's are

Comment: Then you can always just scale everything down to the correct size you need. Just make sure to apply the scales for everything as well.

Comment: @inIimbo the "m" in "12.7601 m" stands for meters

Comment: why would it measure in meters? that has got to be the most inconvienient measurement to have, can it be changed? i cant imagine who would model characters, even architecture in meters!?! there has got to be a better way